# What is the difference between req.on and req.socket.on in an express route?

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between the `req.socket.on` vs. `socket.on` in an express backend route, and what are the capabilities of each?

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    req.on("error", (e) => {
        // do stuff
    });
    req.socket.on("error", (e) => {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to know? is there some specific behavior that you need?

Comment: I want to understand the req object better and what I can do with it, but also I'm trying to figure out how to handle errors sent by a client.